# Can I know the timestamp before the network call of a script tag loading from within the JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

If I am the owner of a third party script and I need to know when that script begins loading, can I do so with JavaScript?

```html
<head>
   <script async defer src="https://example.com/script.js"></script>
</head>
```

Without using server-side analytics, can the script gain access to a timestamp of its own initial point of contact (before the network call for the file is initiated)

```js
// https://example.com/script.js

window.performance.scripts?
document.currentScript.performance?
```

Previously I would use a IIFE to grab the "pre-script" timestamp. Can I do something practically similar?

```js
(() => {
   window._myLibrary.scriptStartTime = new Date()
   const script = document.createElement('script')
   script.src = 'https://example.com/script.js'
   document.head.appendChild(script)
})()
```

Comment: as for me, it's okay.

Comment: Not sure what you exactly want... the time when  the script has been parsed in the DOM?  The time when the request has been initiated? The time when the script actually is being executed? Something else?

Comment: I have just learned that performance is a little more complicated that simply "when the script runs"